# Typescript object with a known property

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Help to define generic, which accepts `Object with type T` and `K property key in T` and returns typed `T`.

My attempts to figure out how it can be solved with TypeScript 4:

1. It solves the problem, but returns `object`. It's not good solution.

```js
type WithProp<TKey extends string> = { [K in TKey]: object };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgBQE4HswB4AqBpCEKCAD2AgDsATAZyhuFTgoHMA%20KAXigG8oBtPFGZR8hALoAuKOgBGAKwgBjYFAC%20AbgBQW0JCgAxdOi68tUKLICGqaQHJrALzsAaLZp1L0FBlABmxtJGJtw85pY29k6u7tpaXj6qJNLwSGiYWHYB6HYcoeHZbhYArhQA1hToAO4U6ZCooPalFdUUUGAY9aBQAG5WADbFEDEe8d6%205AzBpgAU2UHGAJRcHNnak8DBc0vrEFPGMyQAdNmLcQk06P0QR-3oLIdnWkA).

2. The same, but returns `any`. It is better to write something like `T[K]`, but TS said that `TS2536: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'`.

```js
type WithProp<T, K extends string | number> = T & {[keyToSort in K]: any};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgBQE4HswB4AqAaKAaSggA9gIA7AEwGcpbhU5KBzKAHykoFcBbAEYRUAPigBeKDigAyKAG8A2gGsIIHOgDK6VMCgsiAXQBcUAIaUQAXwDcAKDuhIUAGLp0EhXag%20G6PhBomKYA5LT%200GAYYCF4drZ2AMbolIxQAGbupm4ekvLevuEBQWChRZHRsfH2SSlppJ75PpnocT4CZgBeoQCOPKRVCbWpeiCeuCTkVHRQ6AIAVhCJwCIAFCCm8EgluAQhLSEiAJQSYqsFPiCK%20%204hhnZHNcNpFIw5nqst2e4n4mIt9lewBynx%20gIgb3c61WpCOj0cEOBUJAMKOADokHBaCVhKAACLoCEAOXQwAAoqQscB4UA).

---

Usage:

```js
const prop = <K extends string | number>(prop: K) => <T>(model: WithProp<T, K>) => model[prop];
const x = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux'};

typeof prop('foo')(x) === typeof x.foo;
```

And calling the helper with any key (except of `'foo'` or `'baz'`) on `x` must throw an error.

Please, help to write a helper.

Comment: Can you provide a (failing) example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: `const prop = <K extends string | number>(prop: K) => <T extends {[P in K]: any}>(model: T): T[K] => model[prop];`

Comment: @Qurben I've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, then a conditional which checks that `T` contains a property `K` is what you want. Try:

```
type WithProp<T, K extends string|number> = T extends { [k in K]: any } ? T : never
```

Then used with your code:

```
function prop<K extends string | number>(prop: K) {
    return function<T> (model: WithProp<T, K>) { 
        return model[prop];
    }
}

const x = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux' };

typeof prop('foo')(x) === typeof x.foo; // Works

prop('blah')(x); // Error, argument is not assignable to never
```

Not the most descriptive error message, but it gets the job done.

For a better error message, we can re-write things slightly and instead of `WithProp` we can just put the constraint in the template argument list.

```
function prop<K extends string | number>(prop: K) {
    return function<T extends { [k in K]: any }> (model: T) { 
        return model[prop];
    }
}
```

Now we'll get:

```
prop('blah')(x) // Error, Property 'blah' is missing in type '{ foo: string; baz: string; }' but required in type '{ blah: any; }'
```